# Solving Probability using standard Deviation and Mean

Tags: standard-deviation

Given a normal random variable  with mean 90 and a standard deviation 3, find the probability that x is greater than or equal to 86.67 and less than or equal to 96.33

Comment: Do you know how to normalise to standard normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $Y\text{~}N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $X=\frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}\text{~}N(0,1)$.